# Debugging "inconsistent definitions" error in Go

Tags: go, cgo

I'm wrapping a large, complex library with a Go language binding.   At some point, I started getting the following strange error when I ran `go build`:

```
 inconsistent definitions for C.CString
```

I do not, and the library does not define/redefine CString in any way.

I find I'm unable to make a MCVE demonstrating the problem (the code is thousands of lines), but I do have it down to happening/not-happening depending on the presence of a single line:

```
 d := C.FunctionDefinedInLibHeader
```

Of course, if I try to reference this in a minimal example, it works fine.

My question is:   *How can I attempt to debug this error?*  I tried using

```
 go tool cgo
```

to generate the C sources, and nothing looked out of the ordinary (in particular `CString` is only ever called, not defined), and the sources compiled fine.   I just don't understand where that error message is coming from (it's not the C compiler, in particular), or what it even means. But when the C function is referenced in the code, it appears, and when it is not, the problem disappears.

I know there is an [old Go bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8133) which produces a similar error, but in that case the duplicated definition is a library-defined symbol, not a basic cgo internal function.

Comment: Among other things, you can try `go build -x` to see the exact command that produces this error.

Comment: It's the cgo invocation.   I'm trying to write a modified cgo now that emits a more verbose error...

Comment: If you look at main.cgo in the cgo source, it's failing on a line that `reflect.DeepEquals()` the two "conflicting" `Name` entries for `C.CString`.  I've now printed out all of the human-readable (string, int, etc) fields of those two and their children/fields, and they all match exactly.   It's derping somewhere down in the bowels of an `ast.Expr` or possibly an `ast.FuncDecl`.   I'm out of ideas.  =/

Comment: Try looking through the C library source code looking for `CString` type? Maybe try `objdump -tT` on C .so/.a files? If you somehow managed to make a reproducing script, you could open an issue in the Go bug tracker.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's a bug in cgo at this point but I don't want to source-dump 8k+ lines into the bug tracker.  Frustratingly Heisenbuggy!  (also:  I don't think the strings in the Name struct would match if it was a real redefinition... will check as you suggest tho!)

Comment: I've created https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17723 with a verification (if not minimal) example uploaded to a git repo.   I will be adding bounty to this ASAP since it's a showstopper for me.